# Происхождение названия "куриный бог"

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Камни с дыркой называют "куриный бог". А почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Куриный бог (иногда "собачий бог") — небольшой круглый камень; иногда с отверстием естественного происхождения, проточенным водой, речной или морской, иногда носит следы искусственной оработки и изображает голову. Такой камень вешали как обер**е**г в курятниках, чтобы кикиморы не давили кур, или (по другим сведениям) в псарнях, чтобы собаки хорошо спали и были целы, чтобы домовой и кикимора не пугали, не давили и не воровали их.

Камень такой формы (в старонем. «Hascherlit») напоминал громовый молот скандинавского бога Тора.

Название "куриный бог" образовано, возможно, по аналогии со "скотий бог" (славянский бог Волос - покровитель скота).